# Coding bouncing ball on cos curve shaped ground

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am making a game, where world is generated with cos function and it looks like this: 
[image]

At any any x point I can find the height of the surface with functions Game.getHeight(x);

Now I want to make a ball that player can fire, which would bounce properly from surface. The way I did works for about ~5% of the bounces (ie others shoot to ground, bounce off at unrealistic angle etc). How could I improve it? Code I am using:

The ball (bullet) class:

```
package game;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Bullet {

    private final static float speed = 400;
    private final static float acc = 250;
    public final static float radius = 8;

    private int changed;
    private float x, y, speedx, speedy;


    public Bullet (float x, float y, float tx, float ty) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        changed = 0;
        float angle;
        angle = (float) ((float) Math.atan2(y - ty, tx - x) + .5 * Math.PI);
        speedx = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * speed);
        speedy = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * speed);
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame game, int delta) {
        x += speedx * (float) delta / 1000;
        y += speedy * (float) delta / 1000;
        speedy += acc * (float) delta / 1000;
    }

    public void render (Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
        g.drawLine(x, y, (float) (32*Math.sin(getDirection()) + x), (float) (32*Math.cos(getDirection()) + y));
    }

    public void setTrajectory (float angle) {
        float spd = speedx + speedy;
        speedx = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * spd);
        speedy = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * spd);
        changed += 1;
    }

    public float getDirection () {
        return (float) ((float) Math.atan2(-speedy, speedx) + .5 * Math.PI);
    }

    public boolean destroy() {
        return (changed >= 2);          //destroy it after it has bounced off once
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

}
```

The snippet of game update method, where collision is checked:

```
if (bullet != null) {

            bullet.update(gc, game, delta);
            for (float x = bullet.getX() - bullet.radius; x <= bullet.getX()
                    + bullet.radius; x++) {
                if (Point2D.distance(x, getHeight(x), bullet.getX(),
                        bullet.getY()) <= bullet.radius) {
                    float angle;
                    angle = (float) (Math.atan2(getHeight(x - 1)
                            - getHeight(x + 1), -2));

                     angle += (angle - bullet.getDirection());

                    bullet.setTrajectory(angle);
                    if (bullet.destroy()) {
                        bullet = null;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to make that ball bounces properly

Comment: There have been some good (basic) hints in the answers so far. But I think that the collision *detection* that you are doing already might be flawed for some cases. I think it is not sufficient to check whether *any* point between (x-radius) and (x+radius) intersects the ball. You might have have to compute the point on the surface that is closest to the center of the ball, but this is just a gut feeling. Even then, you may miss collisions when the ball moves too fast. In order to detect *all* collisions, you'll have to intersect the ball path and the ground, as LieRyan already said...

Comment: @Marco13 I agree, which is why I'd suggested the separating axis theorem, which should return the vector to move the object from out of the ground, if done right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your first issue could be collision detection between the bullet and the ground, so when I did something similar, [the separating axis theorem](http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55) helped out a lot.

As far as the reaction force goes, it depends on how realistic you want it to look. If you want to be reasonably accurate, I recommend that you look up [suvat](http://www.eloquentmath.com/2012/04/introductory-mechanics-maths-of-snooker.html) equations of motion, and things to do with the [coefficient of restitution](http://www.mathsrevision.net/advanced-level-maths-revision/mechanics/newtons-law-restitution)

If you want to be less accurate, calculate the angle that you hit the surface at, suing the tangent to the surface as 0degrees, and invert the vector about the normal to the plane[image: V1 being the original vector, and V2 being the reaction.]

Answer (score 2):

If you need the physical simulation to be mathematically accurate, you need to solve an equation to find the intersection between the ball's trajectory and the ground, then you need to find the derivative of the ground curve, you can then find the gradient of the curve at the point of intersection by plugging the coordinate of the intersection to the derivative of the ground. Once you found the gradient, you'll need to reflect the ball across the normal of the collision point. You'll need to find the velocity of the ball at collision time and reflect that across the normal of the ground at collision point. The normal is perpendicular to the gradient. If you want inelastic collision like most real world collisions, you'll also need a multiplier to reduce the velocity after the bounce. For extra point, you should consider that the ball may collide shortly after a collision both within a single iteration/time step.

If you just need to make the bounce looks realistic enough, but don't need it to be mathematically accurate, you can find the gradient by finding the height of the curve several pixels to the left and right of the collision point and find the difference. Again you'll need to find the normal and reflect the velocity across the normal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the way you the angle is correct, but its not all you need to do:

1. Find the angle of the surface at the point of collision
2. Find the normal to that angle (perpendicular angle)
3. Find the "length" value between the normal vector and the ball's movement vector
4. Apply this length to the vector along with some coefficient which expresses the "bounciness" of the surface.

Here's the code:

```
angle += Math.PI / 2

PointF normal = new PointF(Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle));
float length = oldMovmentVector.x * normal.x + oldMovmentVector.y * normal.y;

newMovementVector = new PointF();
newMovementVector.x = oldMovmentVector.x - (1 + bounciness) * (length) * normal.x;
newMovementVector.y = oldMovmentVector.y - (1 + bounciness) * (length) * normal.y;

// bounciness is between 0 and 1
// newMovementVector is the new movement vector for your ball.
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

What you care about is the ground's [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_normal). When the ball collides with the world in that slice, you use the ball's trajectory and the surface's normal, and run your calculations using that info.

You should be able to calculate that ahead of time. You can split the world into set of n-pixel wide boxes (a 2d array, or quadtree), each of which is smaller than the diameter of the ball, and calculate the average normal for each.

Slicing has a number of advantages, if you can get away with it. You'll need more than a single point of contact to calculate the surface direction and accurately bounce the ball. Precomputing that for boxes allows you to do a simple lookup, rather than sampling the ground data (or recomputing it) and having to compute the normal every collision.

Comment: My world is randomly generated therefore I don't know anything before run-time.

Comment: I would recommend calculating the surface normals as you generate the world. You have all the necessary data at that time, so keeping those around will only make things faster in the future. Especially since looking up and calculating normals constantly at runtime is going to be a pain awfully quick. Precomputing them also allows you to smooth out the terrain while creating the normals, so tiny details don't cause the ball to glitch out.

Comment: Worlds height is a sum of two cos functions, one with big period and amplitude, other with small period and amplitude. Periods and amplitudes are changed frequently (around once per 3 seconds). In that case is it still viable to pre-calculate? (I can't generate whole world at once because it has no limits how far a player can go).

Comment: I would think so. If you're already storing the world height in a buffer, you can add a second buffer to store normals. When you (re)calculate a section of world, (re)generate the normals. If your world cannot having multiple vertical section (strictly a floor), then you can simple store the normal of each slice in an array. When the ball collides, round the coordinates and find the current slice.